# Framer Motion whileHover won't repeat

Tags: animation, hover, repeat, framer-motion

I cannot get my hover animation to repeat by following the Framer Motion docs here https://www.framer.com/motion/transition/###repeat

The animation properly plays on hover, it just only does it once.
Here is the relevant code:

```
<motion.div
   whileHover={{
     y: [0, -4, 0],
     transition: {
       duration: 0.3,
       repeat: Infinity,
    },
  }}
>...</motion.div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax was correct, my dev environment was not updating properly.